What is the workload like when being a volunteer reviewer for NSF?
For those of us who have volunteered to review grants for the NSF, what was it like? E.g.,

How much time did it take for you?
How many proposals were you asked to review?
How long were the proposals typically?

I'm particularly curious about NSF-MPS and NSF-CISE, but any information would be helpful.

What is -MPS and -CISE?

I was recently a first-time reviewer for an MPS panel.  We were each given 10 proposals to review individually, over 2-3 weeks before the panel meeting.  Proposals are strictly limited to 15 pages for the Project Description (plus additional pages for the budget, etc, which the reviewers don't need to spend as much time on), and most of the proposals used all 15 pages or nearly so.  I found they took me about 2-3 hours each, on average, to read the proposal and write my review.  They got a little faster as I got the hang of it, and I expect that if I'm on a panel again in the future, it won't take as long.
The panel meeting itself was scheduled for 3 full workdays over Zoom, but in our case we were able to finish in 2 days.  Each proposal is assigned a "scribe", a member of the panel who is to take notes of the discussion of that proposal and write up a summary, and so there was some extra work in the evenings of those days to write up my assigned summaries.
All in all, I would estimate I spent about 40-50 hours.  Again, it would probably be somewhat less if it wasn't my first time.  My advice would be to clear your schedule of anything discretionary for 1-2 weeks before the panel, and clear it completely for the days of the panel itself (cancel other meetings, get substitutes for your classes, etc).
By the way, it's not technically "volunteering" because you do get paid: at the time for me it was $600.  That's if you are participating virtually over Zoom, which I think everyone on my panel did.  You also have the option to travel to Washington DC to attend in person, in which case I believe they pay your travel expenses instead; that could be good for networking if most of the rest of the panel is doing the same, but otherwise is probably not worthwhile.
You can work out for yourself what the hourly wage came out to be, but at least it'd cover a nice weekend vacation afterwards, which you'll probably need once you get caught up on your regular work which accumulated during the panel.

Over the many years of reviewing, I've typically estimated that it takes me ~4 hours on average to read a proposal and write a good review. Indeed, the days of the panel, you have to clear your schedule and be present.

This agrees with my experience, though I agree with @WolfgangBangerth that it takes me slightly longer to read and review a proposal well.

What is MPS? ..

MPS = Mathematics and Physical Sciences

I reviewed for CISE recently. I had, IIRC, 4 proposals to review. Reading and writing the review takes me about 3-4 hours per proposal. I try to split them in chunks of 2 hours, as it is intellectually demanding, especially when not exactly in your area. The panel was 2 days, over zoom, and you need to clear the schedule for those days, essentially. They are long, tiring days, and a bit alienating, as 8-hour zoom meetings can be. On the other hand, they are really informative about what the community finds interesting.
